# How to force currency format locale to specific country in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to force the currency formatter to only show specific country currency symbol.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.string(from: cost as NSNumber)
```

How to force currency formatter to specific country symbol ?

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation for `NumberFormatter`? There are several currency related properties.

Comment: `NumberFormatter` objects have a property `currencySymbol`. You could set your `NumberFormatter`'s `currencySymbol` to your desired symbol as the last step in configuring your number formatter and it should override the default symbol for your locale.